# Omit CORS in IONIC App

Tags: json, wordpress, ionic-framework, wp-api

I have an Ionic 3 app in which I calling up wordpress api values from my  website - I would like to omit CORS on my localhost Ionic server as it is telling me the following `Failed to load https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=9&per_page=100: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8100, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.` I am wondering what the best practice is with this?

Thanks.

Comment: please look at this https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: Hi there, thank you for that, I have tried this method of a proxy and was using the npm corsproxy module. However this issue is header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8100, *',